# How to turn a stacked bar chart into a stacked <insert polygon here> chart?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, information-graphics

I have some stacked bar charts that sum to 100%, as shown below:
[image]

Each stacked bar represents a region in a state. I would like to take vectors of each region and fill them with their respective stacked "bar" chart, so you'd have horizontal "stripes" of all 7 stacked values serving as the fill for each region. The goal would be to turn this into an infographic map.

I have the region data, and I have this stacked bar chart for each region and I can bring both into Illustrator CC 2018 as vectors.

How can I go about this in a way that's not entirely manual? Are there some Adobe CC tools that can easily do this? I figured it'd be in Illustrator but I have most of the other programs as well.

Comment: One suggestion I was given was to use a gradient fill for a region, and make the opacity closer to 100% so there's less of a fuzzy gradient look.

Comment: The reason you should be vary of these artistic graphs is that it causes humans to be misled. See many humans appraise this by area so now the stacks might nolonger convey the reasonong that it ought. Unless decieving is indeed the reason ;)

Comment: oh i get it. anything that's a map is technically a distortion of reality as well. this product will complement others in a set i'm currently developing. this is for a proof of concept...hoping it drives discussion and shows them something new more than anything. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Illustrator you can make a wide enough graph and clip it with the wanted closed shape:

[image]

The green shape is dragged onto the graph and defined to be the clipping mask.

Recoloring is possible in any phase. Even the data is editable after clipping and the shape follows (be sure that the new data has the same total sum, here=100)

Edits after clipping can be made in isolation mode. Here data is edited and the artwork is recolored

[image]

Graph framing disappears as soon as one leaves the isolation mode.

**Not asked**, but consider to place traditional easy to read stacks or pies on the map, if they must be on the map.

Comment: perfect. i think this gets at exactly what i was going for. thank you! the bars in the pic i posted are unfinished. there's a design/swatch set up already that i will apply to them in illustrator.